# VFS connection does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, cloud9-ide

I'm following the AWS tutorial [Build a Modern Web Application - [Python]](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-two/).

I'm at **Module 2B: Deploy A Service With AWS Fargate** @step **B:Test The Services Locally**

I run my docker image with success with:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest
```

When I preview the website on AWS cloud9 I get the following error.

```
Oops, VFS connection does not exist
```

I've tried the following:

- created new docker image on different region
- checked the flask app routing (all good)
- double checked my account id
- checked AWS documentation

All of this and I can't figure out what is going on with the error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not run Cloud 9 in a browser in Incognito mode.
2. Remove add blockers
3. Check the docker run output for errors

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and that is to open the console in chrome and do the docker run there.

Here's what it looked like for me

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
- Ad Blockers!
As soon I disable them, It worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use the same (normal) browser, not private mode/incognito window.